# JavaScript - img caption to appear/disappear onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have image caption to appear on 1 mouse click and disappear on next click by using JS. I can't figure out why the image caption is not appearing when I click on the image with onclick event and function use on external JS. Sorry if I make any mistake on question as this is my first post on  the forum.

HTML

```
<div id="section1" >
        <h1>Pictures from my vacation</h1>`enter code here`
        <figure style="float: left;" >
            <img src="Photos/p1.jpg" title="Beach" value="hide/show" onclick="showOrHide()">
            <figcaption id="showthis"  style="visibility: hidden;">Waterton Beach</figcaption>
        </figure>
    <p>Beautiful and Sunny day at Wateron last year. Taking Ferry to explore around the late and natural beauty surrounded there. It was a beatiful day and beach and small town with full of visitors. Hope to back to this beautiful small town on summer break.                                                                                                                                                                                         
    </p>
</div>
```

JS

function showOrHide() {

```
if (show=="false") {

document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility="visible";
show="true";
    
}
else {
//show is true
document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility="hidden";
show="false";
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you declare the `show` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to get you on your way:

1. I wouldn't use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. They can only call global functions, passing parameters to them is difficult because of handling text inside JavaScript code inside an HTML attribute, and various other things. I'd use modern event handling like `addEventListener`.

   But if you did want to use an `onclick` attribute for this, I'd use `onclick="showOrHide(this)"` (`this` will refer to the image that this click was on) and then accept an `img` parameter in the function, rather than using an `id` to do the lookup.
2. Boolean values like `true` and `false` don't go in quotes.
3. You don't seem to have declared your `show` variable anywhere.
4. I'd use a class rather than directly modifying the style of the element.

So with all that in mind:

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
    const img = event.target.closest(".toggle-image");
    if (img && img.nextElementSibling.tagName === "FIGCAPTION") {
        img.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
    <h1>Pictures from my vacation</h1>`enter code here`
    <figure style="float: left;">
        <img src="Photos/p1.jpg" class="toggle-image" title="Beach" value="hide/show">
        <figcaption class="hidden">Waterton Beach</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Beautiful and Sunny day at Wateron last year. Taking Ferry to explore around the late and natural beauty surrounded there. It was a beatiful day and beach and small town with full of visitors. Hope to back to this beautiful small town on summer break.
    </p>
</div>
```

That code uses [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) by hooking click on the document as a whole and then, when the click occurs, seeing if the click was on an `.image-toggle` element (or passed through when bubbling). If it did, it looks at the next element after the `img` to see if it's a `figcaption` and, if so, [toggles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a `hidden` class in the element's [class list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) element to show/hide the caption.

(Those links are to MDN, which is an excellent resource for web programming information.)

Comment: Thank You, I'm a beginner and need this for my assignment. I still need to learn more. Appreciate all the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed some things.

The html code:

```
<div id="section1" >
    <h1>Pictures from my vacation</h1>`enter code here`
    <figure style="float: left;" >
        <img id="myImage" src="https://logowik.com/content/uploads/images/526_liverpoolfc.jpg" title="Beach">
        <figcaption id="showthis"  style="visibility: hidden;">Waterton Beach</figcaption>
    </figure>
<p>Beautiful and Sunny day at Wateron last year. Taking Ferry to explore around the late and natural beauty surrounded there. It was a beatiful day and beach and small town with full of visitors. Hope to back to this beautiful small town on summer break.                                                                                                                                                                                         
</p>
```

I removed the inline onclick property, because it's better to add event listener in the JS like in the code below.
With JS then we add the click listener and we check for the visibility value and we either show or hide it.

The JS code:

```
const myImage = document.getElementById("myImage")
const caption = document.getElementById("showthis")
myImage.addEventListener("click", () => {
 if(caption.style.visibility == "visible") {
  caption.style.visibility = "hidden"
 } else {
  caption.style.visibility = "visible"
 }
```

})

This is doing the toggle functionality. If you want the caption to be over the image, this is a matter of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If displaying/hiding the caption is only your goal, then try this code. This should work.

```
<div id="section1" >
   <h1>Pictures from my vacation</h1>
   <figure style="float: left;" >
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" title="Beach" onclick="showOrHide()">
      <figcaption id="showthis"  style="visibility: hidden;">Waterton Beach</figcaption>
   </figure>
   <p>Beautiful and Sunny day at Wateron last year. Taking Ferry to explore around the late and natural beauty surrounded there. It was a beatiful day and beach and small town with full of visitors. Hope to back to this beautiful small town on summer break.                                                                                                                                                                                       
   </p>
</div>
```

Javascript function should be like this.

```
function showOrHide() {
    const visibility = document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility;
    if (visibility == "hidden") {
        document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

In case you want this javascript function to take care multiple images, you can modify the function like this. and in html on img tag pass the event into function `showOrHide(event)`

```
function showOrHide(e) {
    const img = e.target;
    const figcaption = img.nextElementSibling;
    const visibility = figcaption.style.visibility;
    if (visibility == "hidden") {
        figcaption.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        figcaption.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just a beginner . If I want to have the caption for 5 pictures, do i need to have 5 functions with different IDs or can I use loop to use the same function for 5 pictures? How to use loop in that case ?

Comment: Well in that case, you can use event object to get reference to the element where the event was triggered, and then you can find the nearest figcaption element and show or hide it in a similiar way we did in this function.

Comment: check the edit I made to the answer. this will take care of multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a click event to image. Try with adding an event listener to the image.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="section1">
  <h1>Pictures from my vacation</h1>
  `enter code here`
  <figure style="float: left;">
    <img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644550805208-54b031553153?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1228&q=80"
      title="Beach"
      value="hide/show"
      class="beach-img"
    />
    <figcaption id="showthis" style="visibility: hidden;">
      Waterton Beach
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>
    Beautiful and Sunny day at Wateron last year. Taking Ferry to explore
    around the late and natural beauty surrounded there. It was a beatiful
    day and beach and small town with full of visitors. Hope to back to this
    beautiful small town on summer break.
  </p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let show = false;
const beachImg = document.querySelector(".beach-img")
beachImg.addEventListener("click", function () {
 if (show === false) {
   console.log("showing");
   document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility = "visible";
   show = true;
} else {
   //show is true
   console.log("hiding");
   document.getElementById("showthis").style.visibility = "hidden";
   show = false;
}
```

});

Here's the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-heyrovsky-elwtd?file=/index.html:115-960).

Comment: Thank You , appreciate that. How can I use the same function for 5 different images? How can I loop for that.

Comment: I updated the working example to suit your scenario. Let me know if you have any questions.